# Swift http req. doesnt go through

Tags: swift, http, minecraft

```
//
//  FirstViewController.swift
//  XeGaming
//
//  Created by Brodie Andrew on 6/14/15.
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Count: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var MainDisplay: UIWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://creepertech.net/app/app_urlGrabber.php?url=http://xegaming.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    MainDisplay.loadRequest(request)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func rel(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://creepertech.net/app/app_urlGrabber.php?url=http://xegaming.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    MainDisplay.loadRequest(request)
}

@IBAction func ch(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://creepertech.net/app/app_urlGrabber.php?url=http://ihasabucket.com")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    MainDisplay.loadRequest(request)
}


}
```

the http req on this page and the second page of my app just produces a white blank screen, both of these pages point to xegaming.com, the app url grabber also processes the third and fourth page, both of which work

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are missing the **NSURLSession**, here is a link of how to use the NSURLSession properly: [Link](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c)

Hope this help! :D

Comment: but it always worked before app_urlGrabber was added, and it still works for all pages but those two, all four have the same code

Comment: i also need to point out that it needs to be loaded into the web view "MainDisplay", so i can't use your link, i still need an awnser :l